# Angular 2 material support time in the date picker?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am using angular material version 2.0.0 beta.12

The `<mat-datepicker>` is working fine for me, but I want to add an option to select also hour (time) when selecting the date.

I couldn't find anything [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview/) and in all the list of components in the site of angular material.

Does this version support date**time**picker too?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, angular material currently does not support timepicker,
but the Angular developers [said that this will be developed in 2018](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5648). github.com/angular/material2/issues/5648 –

You can use an [unofficial implementation](https://jumplink.eu/en/blog/post/angular-2-timepicker-for-material-design) of a timepicker until this.

Comment: Does someone knows if it's possible now ?